# Why this NED file don t have design tab?

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to modify one simulation and I find this ned file that don t have design tab ("Design mode"). Name of the file is simulation.ned. Inside this file it s define package, Simulation is define as "simple" module and inside parameters part there are just simulation global parameters.

```
simple Simulator
{
        parameters:

        double LogPeriod= default (3600.0);
        double updatePeriodPN= default (7200.0);
        bool DateTime=default(false); 
        int debugLevel=default(0);
        xml configFileName;

        gates:
        inout directInGate @directIn;
}
```

My question is why this ned file don t have design tab (Design mode)? Is this some kind of special ned file that is present in every simulation (tictoc examples don t have this type of ned file). Other ned files although with a same structure they have design tab (graphical environment)

Comment: What do you mean by "design tab" and "design file"?

Comment: my mistake, thank you for notice.  It s design tab  (Design mode), where you can see simulation in graphical enviroment. This file have just "Source mode" tab, but not "Design mode" tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about the file but rather where the file is. You must configure the `ned folders` in your project settings and only NED files inside the ned folders are shown as dual mode editors. Anything outside the ned folders are shown just as a basic text editor.